# How to access fields in a customized many-to-many through object in templates

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, has-many-through

Consider the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Membership is a customized many-to-may through object with extra fields.
If I have a person instance, how can I access the corresponding date_joined fields of all its membership relations - both in regular code and in a django template file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`person.membership_set.all()` will give you a list of all `Membership` instances for a given `person`. You can use this in regular code as well as in the template.

```
for each in person.membership_set.all():
    print each.date_joined

{% for each in person.membership_set.all %}
    {{ each.date_joined }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you show the view? Consists the dictionary as argument for the render function only of person? Why is the membership_set function written in lower case when the Class Membership is upper?

Comment: because lower case is the convention